# Algorithm for multiplying polynomials using linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list, polynomials

Can you provide me little help with my function for multiplification of two polynomials without adding any new functions? My program works, but it only multiplies all elements of P with the first element of Q. After that, I would like to move the pointer of Q to the second element till the last but I can't figure out how. This is function for multiplification:

```
void multiply(Position Z, Position P, Position Q) {
    P = P->next;
    Q = Q->next;

    while (P != NULL&&Q!=NULL) {
        Z->coeff = P->coeff * Q->coeff;
        Z->exp = P->exp + Q->exp;
        sortedInput(Z, Z->coeff , Z->exp);
        P = P->next;
        
        while(Q!= NULL) {
            Z->coeff = P->coeff * Q->coeff;
            Z->exp = P->exp + Q->exp;
            sortedInput(Z, Z->coeff , Z->exp);
            Q = Q->next;
        }
    }
    
}
```

Whole code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct polinom* Pozicija;

struct polinom {
    int koef;
    int exp;
    Pozicija next;
};

void citaj(Pozicija, char*);

void ispis(Pozicija);
void sortUnos(Pozicija, int, int);
void zbroji(Pozicija, Pozicija, Pozicija);
void pomnozi(Pozicija, Pozicija, Pozicija);

int main() {
    struct polinom P1, P2, Z, U;
    P1.next = NULL;
    P2.next = NULL;
    Z.next = NULL;
    U.next = NULL;

    citaj(&P1, "P1.txt");
    printf("Prvi polinom: ");
    ispis(&P1);

    citaj(&P2, "P2.txt");
    printf("Drugi polinom: ");
    ispis(&P2);
    
    printf("\nZbroj:");
    zbroji(&Z, &P1, &P2);
    ispis(&Z);

    printf("\nUmnozak: ");
    pomnozi(&U, &P1, &P2);
    ispis(&U);
}
void citaj(Pozicija P, char* ime) {
    FILE* dat;
    int k, e;

    Pozicija q = NULL;
    q = (Pozicija)malloc(sizeof(struct polinom));
    
    dat = fopen(ime, "r");
    if (dat == NULL)
        printf("Greska!\n");
    else {
        while (feof(dat) == 0) {
            fscanf(dat, "%d %d", &k, &e);
            
            sortUnos(P, k, e);
            q->koef = k;
            q->exp = e;
        }
    }
    fclose(dat);
}
void ispis(Pozicija P) {
    P = P->next;
    while (P != NULL)
    {
        printf("%dx^%d", P->koef, P->exp);
        P = P->next;
        if (P != NULL)
            printf("+");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void sortUnos(Pozicija P, int k, int e) {
    Pozicija q;
    
    while (P->next != NULL && P->next->exp > e)
        P = P->next;
    q = (Pozicija)malloc(sizeof(struct polinom));

    q->exp = e;
    q->koef = k;

    q->next = P->next;
    P->next = q;
}
void zbroji(Pozicija Z, Pozicija P, Pozicija Q) {
    P = P->next;
    Q = Q->next;
    while (P != NULL && Q != NULL) {
        if (P->exp == Q->exp)
        {
            Z->koef = P->koef + Q->koef;
            Z->exp = P->exp;
            sortUnos(Z, Z->koef, Z->exp);
            P = P->next;
            Q = Q->next;
        }
        else if (P->exp < Q->exp) {
            Z->koef = Q->koef;
            Z->exp = Q->exp;
            sortUnos(Z, Z->koef, Z->exp);
            Q = Q->next;
        }
        else if (P->exp > Q->exp) {
            Z->koef = P->koef;
            Z->exp = P->exp;
            sortUnos(Z, Z->koef, Z->exp);
            P = P->next;
        }
        
        
    }
    if (P == NULL) {
        while (Q != NULL) {
            Z->koef = Q->koef;
            Z->exp = Q->exp;
            sortUnos(Z, Z->koef, Z->exp);
            Q = Q->next;
        }
    }
    else if (Q == NULL) {
        while (P != NULL)
        {
            Z->koef = P->koef;
            Z->exp = P->exp;
            sortUnos(Z, Z->koef, Z->exp);
            P = P->next;
        }
    }   
}
void pomnozi(Pozicija Z, Pozicija P, Pozicija Q) {
    P = P->next;
    Q = Q->next;

    while (P != NULL&&Q!=NULL) {
        Z->koef = P->koef * Q->koef;
        Z->exp = P->exp + Q->exp;
        sortUnos(Z, Z->koef, Z->exp);
        P = P->next;
        
        while(Q!= NULL) {
            Z->koef = P->koef * Q->koef;
            Z->exp = P->exp + Q->exp;
            sortUnos(Z, Z->koef, Z->exp);
            Q = Q->next;
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: There are many problems with this code. How is `Z` initialised? What is `sortedInput`? What is the difference between `coeff` and `koef`? None of this is known, all of this is important. Please provide a [mcve]. The code as posted is likely to crash because it sets `Q` to `NULL` during the first iteration of the outer loop, and dereferences it during subsequent iterations.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I will edit my code now. There is no difference between those, my code is in Croatian and I made a mistake while translating it. sortedInput is a function that initializes polynomials and sorts them automatically in descending order.

Comment: I have to mention that I am loading polynomials from the file, but that shouldn't be a problem. I only want to know how to multiply every single factor of the polynomials.

Comment: Post code you have actually personally compiled and verified. If you need to translate anything, do so before compiling and verifying the code, not after.

Comment: I posted my whole code right now. It should be understandable. Function names are in Croatian. Function zbroji adds two polynomials and function pomnozi should multiply them. Code works, but it doesn't multiply them correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some rather serious problems with this code.

1. `pomnozi` is broken in more than one way. The outer loop starts with multiplying the first member of `P` by the first member of `Q`, and immediately advances `P` so that the first member is never seen again. But you need to multiply the first member of `P` by *all* members of Q, therefore you can only advance `P` *after* it is multiplied by *all* members of `Q`.
2. But if you just move `P = P->next` to a position after the inner loop, you will multiply members of `P` by the first member of `Q` twice. You don't need the outer multiplication at all. All the work should be done in the inner loop.
3. Given a member of `P`, the inner loop of `pomnozi` goes over members of `Q`. Once `Q` is exhausted, the code should go back and multiply `Q` by the next member of `P`, but it cannot, because `Q` is now `NULL` and there is no way to recover it. You need to remember what `Q` was, and re-initialize it in each iteration of the outer loop.
4. `sortUnos` does not check whether the polynomial already has a member with a given exponent, thus, an attempt to multiply e.g. `(x+1) * (x+1)` (supposing `pomnozi` is fixed)  will result in `x` being inserted in the result twice.

You should be able to find these things yourself by using an interactive **debugger**.

There are also other problems. For example, a representation of a linked list where the first node doesn't actually hold any meaningful data is highly error-prone and misleading.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That looks a bit hard though, I will try it. 
Can you provide me the code if you have the time lease? 
Also, in my college classes they have been teaching us to make a dummy element as the head element of the list. Can you explain to me why is that bad?

Comment: How to re-initialize Q, I am stuck on that for 24 hours haha. I have no idea how to fix that.

Comment: I did re-initialize Q using temp values. 
Now, I need to add values with the same coefficient. How to do that?

Comment: (1) Sorry I will not provide code because this defeats the purpose of homework. (2) Having a dummy element in the beginning is not a common practice, therefore it has a hight potential of misleading the reader, and it doesn't translate well to other languages. (3) Think about what you should do when `P->next->exp == e`.

Comment: I made it! Finally! It took more than a day. Thank you for your advices.